# issue about jquery ajax codes

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#page1').click(function() {
            $('#content').load('one.html');
            return false;
        });
        $('#page2').click(function() {
            $('#content').load('two.html');
            return false;
        });     
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" id="page1">page 1</a> | <a href="#" id="page2">page 2</a>
<div id="content">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Above code is taken from [here](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/jQuery-AJAX-P968.html)

Questions:

why this code is called "jquery ajax codes" since it is only using `.load()`, not `.ajax()`? I only know a litte bit about AJAX(Asynchronous JavaScript and XML), how could I change above codes to non-ajax, so I can see the difference  between ajax codes and non-ajax codes?

Comment: Internally it using `ajax` call ..

Comment: Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/load/ so you can get a better idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX stands for "Asynchronous JavaScript and XML" meaning retrieving data from the server Asynchronously (after the page is loaded).. `.load()` does exactly that - this is why it is considered as ajax. I believe it even uses `.ajax()` behind the scenes.

In order to avoid ajax I recommend load both files into containers in your site and only change their visibility using jquery.

For example (using PHP however you can use any other server-side lang):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content1" style="display:none;"><?php include 'one.html';?></div>
<div id="content2" style="display:none;"><?php include 'two.html';?></div>
```

this will ofcourse load the content of the HTML pages synchronously. To avoid asynchronous calls you will have to include all the data on your HTML page.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#page1').click(function() {
            $('#content1').show();
            $('#content2').hide();
        });
        $('#page2').click(function() {
            $('#content2').show();
            $('#content1').hide();
        });     
    });
```

I will elaborate more on the difference. When you use AJAX you don't have to load all the data to the page in advanced. Take the example of which `one.html` and `two.html` contained a very long HTML file.. let's say 500kb each. If you were to use the non AJAX method I offered, your user will have to wait until both were downloaded to see the page (1MB download). When you use the code as you wrote in the question, the loading time of the page is really really low because you only load the structure of the page and not the content. When the user clicks on one of the buttons you will load ONLY the relevant file - meaning 500kb - and you could also display a nice "loading" animation while the page loads. Essentially, this is the main difference - loading the entire data in advanced or loading only the relevant data when it is needed.

A tip to improve your code in the question. after you `.load()` one of the pages, save the data somewhere so if the user clicks on the same button again you won't have to `.load()` again and just use the saved copy.

Comment: THanks for your explanation. I tried the codes u wrote. But what is the difference between ajax codes(original codes I put) and non-ajax codes(the example u gave)? the speed? I can not tell the difference. So could u explain more? thanks

Comment: I've added a more detailed exlanation. Hope this helps.